# WordPress corrupt after installing plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-gallery-custom-links/ and got an error during install that I didn't have time to read before the page refreshed.

Now my media picker didn't load at all.

I removed the plugin completely with no luck, and now I can't even reach the wp-admin anymore. Getting errors like:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/caroli/functions.php:1) in /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1196

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/caroli/functions.php:1) in /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-login.php on line 425

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/caroli/functions.php:1) in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-login.php on line 438

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/caroli/functions.php:1) in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-login.php on line 425

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/caroli/functions.php:1) in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-login.php on line 438

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/vhosts/caroli.hosterspace.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/caroli/functions.php:1) in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 925

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/caroli/functions.php:1) in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 926

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/caroli/functions.php:1) in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 927

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/caroli/functions.php:1) in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1196
```

I have downloaded a fresh copy of wordpress and replaced the wp-admin folder, the wp-includes folder, wp-config.php file, wp-login.php file.

I have tried changing name on the plugins folder, still does not work, I have tried removing my theme to be able to reach the wp-admin, but still doesnt work.

I suspect it might be the database, but i'm out of luck to find the issue.. Can anyone help ?

Comment: How does the beginning of your functions.php look like? Like 10 first rows.

Comment: Does it help if you choose another theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been across this issue several times, **as said by Vaviloff, a space is placed in the beginning of the file (before `<?php`) is the thing your looking for.**

Some possible reasons :

- a corrupted plugin
- a corrupted theme
- *an intrusion in your Wordpress installation (you'll see some eval() in the beginning of the file)*

Possible solutions :

- check the relevant file :  /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/caroli/functions.php:1
  and remove the space before `<?php`
- disable latest plugin you've installed to see if it does anything
- *run a plugin like Wordfence (just in case), it will scan your files
  faster than you could do manually* and check differences with WP core or look for suspicious code (the free version can do all of this)

**EDIT :
I just saw you can't reach wp-admin. That's tricky, but I've had the same problem some times. And well, it was an intrusion (due to an obsolete plugin).**

What did I do ?

- a backup of my theme
- a backup of my DB
- a backup of my uploads
- a list of installed plugins
- changed all passwords
- removed all the relevant part of the server (AFTER ALL BACKUPS)
- reinstalled fresh WP
- restored theme / DB / uploads / plugins (check the last update of your plugins when you install them)
- installed Wordfence, just in case

Comment: Hello, I can not reach the wp-admin so I cant run any plugins.

Answer (score 2):

`Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by`

Means that in some file there already was some text sent to the browser, before end of the script was reached.

`output started at /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/caroli/functions.php:1`

Check that file, there probably is a space in the beginning of the file before `<?php` code start declaration.

I there is no space at the beginning of the file, maybe the culprit is [UTF BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223926/2715393) and you should remove it with the help of a text editor, for example [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) has an option to do that (Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8).

Comment: Unfortunately the issue is not that. I have checked for blank space, I have converted to UTF-8, still no luck

Comment: Well, the error log you provided definitely points at the caroli/functions.php file, line 1. Do you happen to have a backup of that file?